# Conditional Formatting where date is older than 15 days from today

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code to format cells where date is older than 15 days from today. It works on some cells but not others, and also highlights cells that are less than 15 days older.

```vb
Range("C:C").Select  
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=TODAY()-C2>15"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Try `=(TODAY()-C1)>15`

Comment: Thanks Tim.That seems to have fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Refrence: [Excel VBA Conditional Formatting formula within formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678211/excel-vba-conditional-formatting-formula-within-formula).

Try this. These code add a condition that highlight the date older 15days from today on the current sheet's column C

```
Sub formatCondition()
    With ActiveSheet.Range("C:C")
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$C1-TODAY()>15"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = 255
    End With
End Sub
```